# How to put logic inside a dialog? Or make dynamic dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have this dialog that allows the user to select some checkboxes and spinners, to customize an item.

If I add logic to the line that says **// calculation customization here** I can calculate the options after the user presses save.

But I want to calculate the options while the dialog is open, and show dynamic text in the dialog while it is open. Is this possible? Or how can I do it?

```
btnCustomize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override public void onClick(View v){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(itemView.getContext(), R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
        builder.setTitle("Customize");
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_customize, null);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                // User clicked OK button
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                // User cancelled the dialog
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override public void onClick(View v){
                // calculation customization here, after user clicks "Save"
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple  and best way is using DialogFragment, you can define every object and change it, for example :

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),R.style.CustomDialog2);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null ));
            // Add action buttons

    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}  }
```

and in activity create and call it :

```
CustomDialog dialog=new CustomDialog();
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"tag");
```